# WP7 localization does not work

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

I'm trying to do a simple localization of my app, making it support English (default) and Danish. 
I've followed the MS tutorial, and I've looked at some samples but for some reason the simulator does not show the danish version when I choose danish language as the simulator language.

Here's what I've done:

Added supported culture: dk-DK;

Changed assembly info to use "English" as default.

Added the resource to app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LåneRegnskab" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Added "AppResources.resx" and "AppResources.dk-DK.resx" to project with the strings.

To use the strings I write:

```
"{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Title, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

LocalizedStrings class:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    public LocalizedStrings()
    {
    }
    private static AppResources localizedResources = new AppResources();
    public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return localizedResources; } }
}
```

This all works for the english strings, but they do not change when I'm in danish mode. What am I missing here? :(

Comment: Are you using the emulator or an actual device? I noticed that not all devices can be switched to all languages.

Comment: *emulator (a simulation is something else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Claus, I solved my problems (I seem to have made all the mistakes getting there) but here's all the settings that work for me.
I'm supporting English and Spanish and changing the region of the emulator to see it work.

In the **.csproj**

`<SupportedCultures>en;es;</SupportedCultures>` <-- I was being too specific on language here

[image: File names]

I also had `AppResources-es.resx` <-- Rather than .es

In my **GamePage.xaml**
[image: Binding]

I made the mistake here of having `LocalisedStrings` in both source and Path.

In the **App.xaml** I didn't add the namespace inline, but the same otherwise.

[image: App.xaml]

Hopefully it's a mistake in one of these steps as it was in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing obvious wrong with your code. Try force-chance the culture in `App.xaml.cs` with the following code in the  `InitializePhoneApplication` method.

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

**Update**

Also ensure that `SupportedCultures` in your ProjectName.csproj file is set to support both languages, like this: `<SupportedCultures>en;da-DK</SupportedCultures>`

Comment: Verify that a `da-DK` folder is present in the output folder.

Comment: Hmm in my bin -> debug and bin -> release theres a dk-DK folder yes. Inside this is a dll for some advertisement: "Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.resources".
There's folders for all other languages too, all with that file as the only content.

Comment: It's meant to contain a `<ProjectName>.appresources.dll` file. So this points to that your Resource Files aren't compiled correctly. That would also explain why forcing a culture have no effect.

Comment: Verify that your compilation-settings for the resource file(s) looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1744224/vs_danish_resources.png

Comment: It's still not compiling your `AppResources.da-DK.resx` correctly. The default (English) resources are compiled correctly. Verify that the `AppResources.da-DK.Designer.cs` is **empty** (it shouldn't contain any code, at all)

Comment: It contained a lot of code, I've deleted everything but as far as I can see, it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Not the point. If it contains code, it means it's not recognized as the Danish localization for the AppResources.resx ! Are you 110% sure on the filename spelling?

Comment: Re-create the resource files. You need to fix the compilation of them.

Comment: Re-created the files, but no luck .... tried creating a whole new project - still no luck...

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Wrap up a test project in a zip, and I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem and I've just found the solution. In the csproj file the  node is defined by default, but I didn't noticed that and I created another one at the first lines...

So if you remove this(or set your cultures here) it will probably work.

```
<SilverlightApplication>true</SilverlightApplication>
<SupportedCultures>
</SupportedCultures>
<XapOutputs>true</XapOutputs>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the csproj file as in the example bellow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941931%28v=vs.95%29.aspx